# Using Reticulate to Run a Python Script with Arguments

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I have a python script that has kindly been developed by one of our architects here. I would like to execute it in `R` using the `Reticulate` package. The script acts like an API to one of our systems. I call it on my machine providing it with a number and it spits out a JSON file for me.

I can see from looking at the documentation that it is possible to run the script using `py_run_file(file)`. I am able to use this to run the script but it fails when I add arguments saying it does not know where the file is. It all works perfectly via the command prompt and the file can be found when i don't include the arguments.

I am aware I could just wrap the cmd prompt in R to execute the script via python but was wondering if its possible to just submit the command to `Reticulate` and get back the results. Below is a pseudo-code example

```r
library(reticulate)
file = 'C:/Users/foo/Documents/util/account_number.py -n 9998877'
py_run_file(file)
```

> Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) :  Unable to open file
> 'C:/Users/foo/Documents/util/account_number.py -n 9998877' (does it
> exist?)

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer [here](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/calling_python.html#sourcing-scripts)

So i source the python script in R and have access to all its functions my environment. Applying that to my own problem above

```r
library(reticulate)
file = 'C:/Users/foo/Documents/util/account_number.py'
source_python(file)
search_account('9998877')
```

I hope other people find this useful

Thanks